# MULTIPLEXER with 6 digital input channels and two ENABLE signals (one low and one high)

Tags: vhdl

Objective: simulation of an elementary VHDL circuit;

Present the VHDL code and a result of the simulation of a MULTIPLEXER circuit with 6 digital input channels and two ENABLE signals (one low asset and one high asset).

I think something is missing, or something is wrong.
I only do with 4 channels, but in my work, I need 6

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity TrabalhoPratico1 is
port (

ch1: in std_logic;
ch2: in std_logic;
ch3: in std_logic;
ch4: in std_logic;
ch5: in std_logic;
ch6: in std_logic;
saida1 : in std_logic;
saida2 : in std_logic;
z: out std_logic);

end TrabalhoPratico1;

architecture mux6 of TrabalhoPratico1 is
begin
process (ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4,saida1,saida2) is
begin

    if (ch1 = '0' and saida1= '0') then
        z <=a ch1;
    elsif (ch1 = '1' and saida1= '0') then
        z <=a ch2;
    elsif (ch1 = '0' and saida1= '1') then
        z <=a ch3;
    else
        z <=a ch3;
    else
        z <=a ch4;
    end if;

end process;
end mux6;
```

Comment: I think the ENABLE signals are separate from a SELECT signal (which has to be 3 bits).

Comment: I think something is lost in translation here. From Google Translate I get that `saida1` and `saida2` mean `exit1` and `exit2`, but they are declared as inputs. You also seem to be using `ch1` as a select signal. Should you not rename `saida1` and `saida2` to `selecionar1` and `selecionar2` and use those to select the correct `ch` to assign to `z`? And add a new `selecionar3` for 3 bits as suggested by @brian-drummond?